# I'm trying to append my a tag to my li tag but it doesn't seem to be working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to append my a tag to my li tag and then add that li to the messages id, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working.

When I append the message.url to #messages it prints to the screen fine, but when I append the var a to the screen it doesn't show up. Not quite sure what is going on, I've tried just about everything I can think of.

```
socket.on('newLocationMessage', function (message) {
    var li = $('<li></li>');
    var a = $('<a target="_blank"><My current location</a>');

    li.text(`${message.from}: `);
    a.attr('href', message.url);

    li.append(a);
    $('#messages').append(li);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simply way to solve your question without *.text* or *.attr*.
If you could provide your sample code(HTML) to here, it will be helpful.

```js
// find elements
var button = $("button");

// handle event like newLocationMessage event
button.on("click", function() {
  //replace your data
  let message = {
    url: "https://google.com",
    from: "Google"
  };
  var li = $('<li><a target="_blank" href="' + message.url + '">' + message.from + '</a></li>');
  $('#messages').append(li);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<button>
trigger
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It had an extra < next to My current location!

```
socket.on('newLocationMessage', function (message) {
    var li = $('<li></li>');
    var a = $('<a target="_blank"><My current location</a>');

    li.text(`${message.from}: `);
    a.attr('href', message.url);

    li.append(a);
    $('#messages').append(li);
});
```